# How to retrieve a value from Tkinter class and use it in another?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have run into a problem with Tkinter and I cannot figure it out with hours of Googling. I found a large chunk of code which creates a calendar in Tkinter and returns the date in a certain format. When I use another class to try and access that data, it returns either errors, the location of where the text is stored, or just not what I need at all.

Here is the baseline code which creates a tkinter calendar application (credit to Rambarun Komaljeet)

```
import calendar
import tkinter as tk
import time
from tkinter import ttk
import sys

class MyDatePicker(tk.Toplevel):
    """
    Description:
        A tkinter GUI date picker.
    """

    def __init__(self, widget=None, format_str=None):
        """
        :param widget: widget of parent instance.

        :param format_str: print format in which to display date.
        :type format_str: string

        Example::
            a = MyDatePicker(self, widget=self.parent widget,
                             format_str='%02d-%s-%s')
        """

        super().__init__()
        self.widget = widget
        self.str_format = format_str

        self.title("Date Picker")
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.geometry("+630+390")

        self.init_frames()
        self.init_needed_vars()
        self.init_month_year_labels()
        self.init_buttons()
        self.space_between_widgets()
        self.fill_days()
        self.make_calendar()

    def init_frames(self):
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame1.pack()

        self.frame_days = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame_days.pack()

    def init_needed_vars(self):
        self.month_names = tuple(calendar.month_name)
        self.day_names = tuple(calendar.day_abbr)
        self.year = time.strftime("%Y")
        self.month = time.strftime("%B")

    def init_month_year_labels(self):
        self.year_str_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.month_str_var = tk.StringVar()

        self.year_str_var.set(self.year)
        self.year_lbl = tk.Label(self.frame1, textvariable=self.year_str_var,
                                 width=3)
        self.year_lbl.grid(row=0, column=5)

        self.month_str_var.set(self.month)
        self.month_lbl = tk.Label(self.frame1, textvariable=self.month_str_var,
                                  width=8)
        self.month_lbl.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def init_buttons(self):
        self.left_yr = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text="←", width=5,
                                  command=self.prev_year)
        self.left_yr.grid(row=0, column=4)

        self.right_yr = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text="→", width=5,
                                   command=self.next_year)
        self.right_yr.grid(row=0, column=6)

        self.left_mon = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text="←", width=5,
                                   command=self.prev_month)
        self.left_mon.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.right_mon = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text="→", width=5,
                                    command=self.next_month)
        self.right_mon.grid(row=0, column=2)

    def space_between_widgets(self):
        self.frame1.grid_columnconfigure(3, minsize=40)

    def prev_year(self):
        self.prev_yr = int(self.year_str_var.get()) - 1
        self.year_str_var.set(self.prev_yr)

        self.make_calendar()

    def next_year(self):
        self.next_yr = int(self.year_str_var.get()) + 1
        self.year_str_var.set(self.next_yr)

        self.make_calendar()

    def prev_month(self):
        index_current_month = self.month_names.index(self.month_str_var.get())
        index_prev_month = index_current_month - 1

        #  index 0 is empty string, use index 12 instead,
        # which is index of December.
        if index_prev_month == 0:
            self.month_str_var.set(self.month_names[12])
        else:
            self.month_str_var.set(self.month_names[index_current_month - 1])

        self.make_calendar()

    def next_month(self):
        index_current_month = self.month_names.index(self.month_str_var.get())

        try:
            self.month_str_var.set(self.month_names[index_current_month + 1])
        except IndexError:
            #  index 13 does not exist, use index 1 instead, which is January.
            self.month_str_var.set(self.month_names[1])

        self.make_calendar()

    def fill_days(self):
        col = 0
        #  Creates days label
        for day in self.day_names:
            self.lbl_day = tk.Label(self.frame_days, text=day)
            self.lbl_day.grid(row=0, column=col)
            col += 1

    def make_calendar(self):
        #  Delete date buttons if already present.
        #  Each button must have its own instance attribute for this to work.
        try:
            for dates in self.m_cal:
                for date in dates:
                    if date == 0:
                        continue

                    self.delete_buttons(date)

        except AttributeError:
            pass

        year = int(self.year_str_var.get())
        month = self.month_names.index(self.month_str_var.get())
        self.m_cal = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)

        #  build dates buttons.
        for dates in self.m_cal:
            row = self.m_cal.index(dates) + 1
            for date in dates:
                col = dates.index(date)

                if date == 0:
                    continue

                self.make_button(str(date), str(row), str(col))

    def make_button(self, date, row, column):
        """
        Description:
            Build a date button.

        :param date: date.
        :type date: string

        :param row: row number.
        :type row: string

        :param column: column number.
        :type column: string
        """
        exec(
            "self.btn_" + date + " = ttk.Button(self.frame_days, text=" + date
            + ", width=5)\n"
            "self.btn_" + date + ".grid(row=" + row + " , column=" + column
            + ")\n"
            "self.btn_" + date + ".bind(\"<Button-1>\", self.get_date)"
        )

    def delete_buttons(self, date):
        """
        Description:
            Delete a date button.

        :param date: date.
        :type: string
        """
        exec(
            "self.btn_" + str(date) + ".destroy()"
        )

    def get_date(self, clicked=None):
        """
        Description:
            Get the date from the calendar on button click.

        :param clicked: button clicked event.
        :type clicked: tkinter event
        """

        clicked_button = clicked.widget
        year = self.year_str_var.get()
        month = self.month_str_var.get()
        date = clicked_button['text']

        self.full_date = self.str_format % (date, month, year)
        print(self.full_date)
        sys.stderr.write(self.full_date)
        #  Replace with parent 'widget' of your choice.
        try:
            self.widget.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.widget.insert(0, self.full_date)
        except AttributeError:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def application():
        MyDatePicker(format_str='%02d-%s-%s')

    root = tk.Tk()
    btn = tk.Button(root, text="test", command=application)
    btn.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

What I've been trying to do is get that data back into the first tkinter box that I open so I can use it for a search feature. It seems that the actual stuff I need is in the `get_date()` section where it pulls information and prints out the date in the console as the variable `self.full_date`.

How do I get this to work within a different class? This is what I have so far (the `MyDatePicker` is also there but I didn't want to clutter too much space)

```
class Main_Window(tk.Frame,MyDatePicker):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root=root
        #self.MyDatePicker=MyDatePicker()
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root.geometry('300x300')
        b1 = tk.Button(self.root, text="Add another window", command =lambda: self.newWindow(1))
        b1.grid(column=1, row=1)
        self.total = 0
        self.count=0
        self.total_label_text = tk.IntVar()
        self.total_label_text.set(self.total)
        #self.total_label_text
        self.lbl1=tk.Label(self.root,textvariable=self.total_label_text)
        self.lbl1.grid(column=1,row=2)

        b2 = tk.Button(self.root, text="Add another window", command =lambda: self.newWindow(2))
        b2.grid(column=2, row=1)
        self.total2 = 0
        self.count2=0
        self.total_label_text2 = tk.IntVar()
        self.total_label_text2.set(self.total2)
        #self.total_label_text
        self.lbl2=tk.Label(self.root,textvariable=self.total_label_text2)
        self.lbl2.grid(column=2,row=2)

        b1 = tk.Button(self.root, text="Add another window", command =lambda: self.press_calendar(format_str='%02d-%s-%s',Class=MyDatePicker))
        b1.grid(column=1, row=1)


    def press_calendar(self,format_str,Class):
        self.MyDatePicker1=Class(format_str)
        self.MyDatePicker1.get_date(self)

    def newWindow(self,m):
        if m ==1:
            self.count += 1
        if m ==2:
            self.count2+=1
        self.window = tk.Toplevel(self)

        but1=tk.Button(self.window,text="Add One",command =lambda:self.close(m))
        but1.grid(row=2,column=1)
    def close(self,m):
        if m==1:
            self.total_label_text.set(self.count)
        if m==2:
            self.total_label_text2.set(self.count2)
        self.window.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Main_Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to make this happen in the `press_calendar` part of my code where I call the other class, run it, and have it return the date.

All I'm getting is the variable location or I have to initialize all the variables from the `MyDatePicker` in the `Main_Window` class.

What can I do better to actually retrieve the date and use it in my main window?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please reduce the code down to a [mcve]. You’ve posted way too much irrelevant code

Comment: @BryanOakley, The reason I posted so much was to show my specific methodology for how I structured my classes and called my specific windows and buttons.
The first massive code block was just copied and pasted in case anyone wanted to take it themselves and see how it runs. I'll go and edit my code down to try and only post what is relevant.

Comment: Also @BryanOakly, you are a huge help and I've been reading all your documentation from previous posts and I'm very appreciative of you :D

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the `MyDatePicker()` class is not intended to be inherited, but used as a server. In my example I'm calling `MyDatePicker()` and providing the widget of master where I'd like the date string to be sent.

```
class Main_Window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry('300x300')

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.pack()

        b1 = tk.Button(self, text="Pick date", command=self.pick_date)
        b1.grid(column=0, row=0)

        # Widget to recieve date string from MyDatePicker
        self.date_display = tk.Entry(self, text='apa', width=20)
        self.date_display.grid(column=0, row=1)

    def pick_date(self):
        # Call MyDatePicker and provide widget to recieve date string
        picker = MyDatePicker(widget=self.date_display, format_str='%02d-%s-%s')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Main_Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

You will have to remove the `if __name__ == "__main__":` section from the `MyDatePicker()` code for it to function if the are to be in the same file.